# java.io.IOException: Failed to send RPC 6769565832902301993 to /10.128.226.240:45541: java.lang.AbstractMethodError

Tags: java, apache-spark, netty

this project use spark_core 2.2.0 and netty 4.16.0 final.I would load Randomforest model into my project by spark, but it can't work.
I would use spark to load model follow this code, but some error happen in loading model.
what should I do that can solve this question?
is it the version correspondence between spark and netty?
why it can't work？

```java
    public static  PipelineModel loadPipelineModel(){
        if(pipelineModel==null){
            synchronized (DataMineService.class){
                if(pipelineModel == null){
                    pipelineModel = PipelineModel.load("/home/geray/IdeaProjects/Dejavu/backend/util-service-provider-8001/src/main/java/com/buptse/model/rf.model/");
                }
            }
        }
        return pipelineModel;
    }
    @PostMapping("/predict")
    public CommonResult predict(
            @RequestParam("brand") Integer brand,
            @RequestParam("fuelType") Integer fuelType,
            @RequestParam("gearBox") Integer gearBox,
            @RequestParam("kilometer") Integer kilometer,
            @RequestParam("unrepairedDamage") Integer unrepairedDamage
    ) {

        List<Row> data = Collections.singletonList(RowFactory.create(brand, fuelType, gearBox, kilometer, unrepairedDamage,
                DataMineService.V0, DataMineService.V2,
                DataMineService.V3, DataMineService.V4, DataMineService.V6));
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("RandomForest").setMaster("local");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        PipelineModel model = DataMineService.pipelineModel == null ?
                DataMineService.loadPipelineModel() : DataMineService.pipelineModel;
        SQLContext sql = new SQLContext(sc);
        Dataset<Row> dataFrame = sql.createDataFrame(data, DataMineService.schema);
        Dataset<Row> prediction = model.transform(dataFrame);
        Double  price= (Double) prediction.select("prediction").collect();
        System.out.println(price);
        return CommonResult.success(PredictDto.genPredictDto(price));

    }
```

follows error

```java
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: null
    at io.netty.util.ReferenceCountUtil.touch(ReferenceCountUtil.java:73) ~[netty-all-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.touch(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:107) ~[netty-all-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:821) [netty-all-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:734) [netty-all-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageEncoder.write(MessageToMessageEncoder.java:111) ~[netty-all-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749) [netty-all-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:741) [netty-all-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:827) [netty-all-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:734) [netty-all-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.write(IdleStateHandler.java:284) ~[netty-all-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749) [netty-all-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:741) [netty-all-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$1900(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:39) [netty-all-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$AbstractWriteTask.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1100) ~[netty-all-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$WriteAndFlushTask.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1147) ~[netty-all-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$AbstractWriteTask.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1089) ~[netty-all-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163) ~[netty-all-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:418) ~[netty-all-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:454) ~[netty-all-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:873) ~[netty-all-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144) ~[netty-all-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_275]
2021-09-07 18:16:06.405 ERROR 36802 --- [ffle-client-8-1] o.a.s.n.shuffle.OneForOneBlockFetcher    : Failed while starting block fetches

java.io.IOException: Failed to send RPC 6769565832902301993 to /10.128.226.240:45541: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.notifyOutboundHandlerException(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:847) ~[netty-all-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:751) ~[netty-all-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:741) ~[netty-all-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:827) ~[netty-all-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:734) ~[netty-all-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.write(IdleStateHandler.java:284) ~[netty-all-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749) ~[netty-all-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:741) ~[netty-all-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$1900(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:39) ~[netty-all-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$AbstractWriteTask.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1100) ~[netty-all-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$WriteAndFlushTask.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1147) ~[netty-all-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$AbstractWriteTask.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1089) ~[netty-all-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163) ~[netty-all-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:418) ~[netty-all-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:454) ~[netty-all-4.1.6.Final.jar:4.1.6.Final]
```

Comment: I believe Spark has its own versions of netty, yes, which you may refer to in the Spark source code

Comment: ,it happen this error follow when I remove netty dependency
```java
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: DEFAULT_TINY_CACHE_SIZE
 at org.apache.spark.network.util.NettyUtils.getPrivateStaticField(NettyUtils.java:131) ~[spark-network-common_2.11-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]

```

Comment: thanks for your help, I solve this problem by alter version of netty.

Comment: Feel free to provide your full solution below as an answer rather than a comment